# Python/Tkinter: Trap text selection via keyboard/mouse as an event?

Tags: python, windows, events, user-interface, tkinter

Is it possible to trap text selection via the keyboard AND mouse as a selection/selection_change type of event? (I know I can trap selection via the keyboard by watching every keypress and comparing selection range - but I see no way to detect selection via the mouse or as a discrete event by itself)

I've looked at the following Tkinter event documentation and don't see a selection/selection_changed type of event.
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/events.html

Perhaps some of you Tkinter/Tk veterans might have some clever ideas?

Thank you,
Malcolm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text widget generates a `<<Selection>>` event, and the listbox generates a `<<ListboxSelect>>` event. Do either of those meet your needs?

Comment: <embarrassed/> I totally missed the Text widget's <Selection> event. That is exactly what I'm looking for. Is there a <Selection> type event for Entry and Spinner widgets? (I tried binding <Selection> on an Entry widget and received an error message).

Comment: @Malcolm, @Bryan Oakley: That `<Selection>` event does not work, I get this error: `_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Selection"`. I've done the checking in another way using `SEL_FIRST` and `SEL_LAST`: `text.index(SEL_FIRST)` on the text widget.

Comment: @Czarek: my bad. It's `<<Selection>>`, not `<Selection>`. I've updated my answer.