# How to configure default Double Mouse Click behavior in Tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

On a tkinter text widget, the default behavior of double click will be to select the text under the mouse.

The event will select all characters between " " (space) char.

So - assume the text widget has:
`1111111 222222` 
double click on over the first word (all `1`) will select only it (and double clicking on `2` word will select it)

I would like to have a similar behavior, but add additional char as work seperators (e.g., `.`, `(`, `)`)
currently, if the text has `111111.222222` - double click anywhere over the text will highlight all characters (won't separate the words by `.`)

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Changing what is a 'word'

The double click is defined to select the 'word' under the cursor. If you are wanting to change the default behavior for all text widgets, tkinter has a way to tell it what is a "word" character. If you change what tkinter thinks is a "word", you change what gets selected with a double-click. This requires that we directly call the built-in tcl interpreter upon which tkinter is based.

Note: this will affect other aspects of the widget as well, such as key bindings for moving the cursor to the beginning or ending of a word.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def set_word_boundaries(root):
    # this first statement triggers tcl to autoload the library
    # that defines the variables we want to override.  
    root.tk.call('tcl_wordBreakAfter', '', 0) 

    # this defines what tcl considers to be a "word". For more
    # information see http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/library.htm#M19
    root.tk.call('set', 'tcl_wordchars', '[a-zA-Z0-9_.,]')
    root.tk.call('set', 'tcl_nonwordchars', '[^a-zA-Z0-9_.,]')

root = tk.Tk()
set_word_boundaries(root)

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text.insert("end", "foo 123.45,678 bar")

root.mainloop()
```

### Custom key binding

If you do not want to affect any widget except one, or do not want to affect other aspects of tkinter that depend on the definition of a 'word', you can create your own binding to select whatever you want.

The important thing to remember is that your binding should return the string `"break"` in order prevent the default behavior for double-click:

```
def handle_double_click(event):
    <your code for selecting whatever you want>
    return "break"
...
text.bind("<Double-1>", handle_double_click)
```

To facilitate this, the text widget has a `search` method that makes it possible to search backwards and forwards through the text for a given string or regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do it?

Of course, and not even one way. But anyway - we need a custom class for our `Text` widget, so let's start:

```
class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, delimiters=[]):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent)
        #   test text
        self.insert('1.0', '1111111 222222'
                           '\n'
                           '1111111.222222'
                           '\n'
                           '1111111.222222,333333'
                           '\n'
                           '444444444444444444')
        #   binds
        self.bind('<Double-1>', self.on_dbl_click)
        self.bind('<<Selection>>', self.handle_selection)
        #   our delimiters
        self.delimiters = ''.join(delimiters)
        #   stat dictionary for double-click event
        self.dbl_click_stat = {'clicked': False,
                               'current': '',
                               'start': '',
                               'end': ''
                               }
```

The optional `delimiters` leads to two options:

1. *If delimiters are presented* we can rely on RegEx [`search`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.search-method) for delimiters.
2. *If delimiters are ommited* we can rely on build-in expressions, especially those two (RegEx-like word boundaries): `wordstart` and `wordend`. According to [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm):

   > `wordstart` and `wordend` moves the index to the beginning (end) of the current word. Words are sequences of letters, digits, and underline, or single non-space characters.

The logic is simple - when double click occures - we trace this event and store indexes in a dictionary. After that we handle change of the selection, and act accordingly the choosen option (see above).

Here's a complete snippet:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, delimiters=[]):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent)
        #   test text
        self.insert('1.0', '1111111 222222'
                           '\n'
                           '1111111.222222'
                           '\n'
                           '1111111.222222,333333'
                           '\n'
                           '444444444444444444')

        #   binds
        self.bind('<Double-1>', self.on_dbl_click)
        self.bind('<<Selection>>', self.handle_selection)
        #   our delimiters
        self.delimiters = ''.join(delimiters)
        #   stat dictionary for double-click event
        self.dbl_click_stat = {'clicked': False,
                               'current': '',
                               'start': '',
                               'end': ''
                               }

    def on_dbl_click(self, event):
        #   store stats on dbl-click
        self.dbl_click_stat['clicked'] = True
        #   clicked position
        self.dbl_click_stat['current'] = self.index('@%s,%s' % (event.x, event.y))
        #   start boundary
        self.dbl_click_stat['start'] = self.index('@%s,%s wordstart' % (event.x, event.y))
        #   end boundary
        self.dbl_click_stat['end'] = self.index('@%s,%s wordend' % (event.x, event.y))


    def handle_selection(self, event):
        if self.dbl_click_stat['clicked']:
            #   False to prevent a loop
            self.dbl_click_stat['clicked'] = False
            if self.delimiters:
                #   Preserve "default" selection
                start = self.index('sel.first')
                end = self.index('sel.last')
                #   Remove "default" selection
                self.tag_remove('sel', '1.0', 'end')
                #   search for occurrences
                occurrence_forward = self.search(r'[%s]' % self.delimiters, index=self.dbl_click_stat['current'],
                                                 stopindex=end, regexp=True)
                occurrence_backward = self.search(r'[%s]' % self.delimiters, index=self.dbl_click_stat['current'],
                                                  stopindex=start, backwards=True, regexp=True)

                boundary_one = occurrence_backward + '+1c' if occurrence_backward else start
                boundary_two = occurrence_forward if occurrence_forward else end
                #   Add selection by boundaries
                self.tag_add('sel', boundary_one, boundary_two)
            else:
                #   Remove "default" selection
                self.tag_remove('sel', '1.0', 'end')
                #   Add selection by boundaries
                self.tag_add('sel', self.dbl_click_stat['start'], self.dbl_click_stat['end'])


root = tk.Tk()

text = CustomText(root)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In conclusion, if you doesn't really care about delimiters, but about words - the second option is OK, otherwise - the first one.

*Update:*

Many thanks to @Bryan Oakley for pointing that `'break'`-string prevents the default behaviour, so code can be shortened to just one callback, there's no need in `<<Selection>>` anymore:

```
...
def on_dbl_click(self, event):
    if self.delimiters:
        #   click position
        current_idx = self.index('@%s,%s' % (event.x, event.y))
        #   start boundary
        start_idx = self.search(r'[%s\s]' % self.delimiters, index=current_idx,
                                stopindex='1.0', backwards=True, regexp=True)
        #   quick fix for first word
        start_idx = start_idx + '+1c' if start_idx else '1.0'
        #   end boundary
        end_idx = self.search(r'[%s\s]' % self.delimiters, index=current_idx,
                              stopindex='end', regexp=True)
    else:
        #   start boundary
        start_idx = self.index('@%s,%s wordstart' % (event.x, event.y))
        #   end boundary
        end_idx = self.index('@%s,%s wordend' % (event.x, event.y))

    self.tag_add('sel', start_idx, end_idx)
    return 'break'
...
```

Comment: Thanks - i'll give it a try - btw: where does `<<sellection>>` virtual event is documented? i didn't find it in the docs i was looking at...

Comment: @NirMH, uhm, unfortunately I can refer only to [Brian's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165045/python-tkinter-trap-text-selection-via-keyboard-mouse-as-an-event). I can't find any of doc's references either.

Comment: @NirMH: The `<<Selection>>` virtual event is documented in the canonical documentation for the tk library (upon which tkinter is built) here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M62