# How to trap a Text object selection event in Python3 / tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

Per the following Stackoverflow wisdom

[Python/Tkinter: Trap text selection via keyboard/mouse as an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165045/python-tkinter-trap-text-selection-via-keyboard-mouse-as-an-event)

I tried to detect the creation of a user selection in a Text object as follows

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_selection(e=None):
    print('here')
    try:
        sel_first = input_text.index(tk.SEL_FIRST)
        sel_last = input_text.index(tk.SEL_LAST)
        print(sel_first, sel_last)
    except:
        return

def main():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Simple Text Editor")
    
    input_text = tk.Text(window)
   
    input_text.bind("<<Selection>>", handle_selection)
    input_text.pack()
    window.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However the event is triggered (apparently) for each horizontal pixel selected rather than when the selection is completed, which was my intention. I also tried the following

```
input_text.bind("<<Selection-ButtonRelease>>", handle_selection)
```

which wasn't triggered at all.

Is there a way to capture the event when the user releases the button after making the selection?

Comment: Have you considered just binding on `<ButtonRelease>` and then seeing if the selection is non-empty?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, that event also wasn't triggered at all. I've updated the my question with a complete working example.

Comment: Did you try `input_text.bind("<ButtonRelease>", handle_selection)` as @BryanOakley suggested? I managed to get things working that way.

Comment: @JRiggles Ackpfft! I was using double brackets around the event name. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That'll get ya every time!

Comment: When I bind to `<ButtonRelease>` the function is called as expected. Also, you have a bug in your handler - `input_text` is local to `main` and thus not visible to `handle_selection`.

Comment: @BryanOakley It was a problem with too many brackets :-) Thanks for the tip.